# Completion Handler deprecated for UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using a UIActivityViewController to share content from within my app. When the activity is completed, I want to turn off the UITableView editing mode. However looking at the documentation I saw that the completionHandler property of UIActivityViewController has been deprecated as of iOS 8.0. There is no deprecation statement from what I can see, I am wondering what the new sanctioned way of doing this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the property description is the same seems like you should use *completionWithItemsHandler*

The completion handler to execute after the activity view controller is dismissed.

> @property(nonatomic, copy) UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler completionWithItemsHandler
>
> When the user-selected service
> finishes operating on the data, or when the user dismisses the view
> controller, the view controller executes this completion handler to
> let your app know the final result of the operation.

Comment: It looks like that property is only listed when you view it on the web, as opposed to the offline Xcode documententation, no wonder I missed it! I'm not a registered developer, but someone should file a radar.